# How to change the input value of an inline-blocked blank field to single-byte alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any CSS setting that allows only single-byte alphanumeric characters to be entered into a blank field that has been set to inline-block?

Currently, I have the following settings in HTML and CSS.
HTML

```
<div id="CodeText" contenteditable="true" class="ui-state-highlight">1244</div>
```

CSS

```
#CodeText {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

With the above configuration, if a value other than a single-byte alphanumeric value is entered for CodeText, is there any way to suppress it?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: CSS doesn't really deal with content. I think you'll have to resort to JS.

Comment: I had answer using JS which has been downvoted, I assume because it uses JS. If a JS solution is useful to you I’ll reinstate it.

Comment: Ah Thanks, I guess there is no solution by using CSS.I'll see if there is a way to do it with JS.
Thank you very much.